# UWP cannot set the text in a textbox after navigating back from another page

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, windows-10, windows-10-universal

I have a UWP app. There is a scanner control that I call to do some barcode scanning via the camera. It has a callback to give the results back via an Action. So, basically, I am on MainPage and I click to launch the scanner like this:

```
scanner.Scan(scanOptions).ContinueWith(t =>
{
    if (t.Result != null)
        HandleScanResult(t.Result);
});
```

The above call, in the scanner.Scan method, will call a Frame.Navigate to go the the scanner control page. After the scan is complete, I first call a Frame.Navigate to come back to MainPage and then return the Result which will call the above HandleScanResult inside of ContinueWith. This is how I navigate to the scan page and back:

```
public override async Task<Result> Scan(MobileBarcodeScanningOptions options)
{
    var rootFrame = RootFrame ?? Window.Current.Content as Frame ?? ((FrameworkElement) Window.Current.Content).GetFirstChildOfType<Frame>();
    var dispatcher = Dispatcher ?? Window.Current.Dispatcher;

    var tcsScanResult = new TaskCompletionSource<Result>();

    await dispatcher.RunAsync(CoreDispatcherPriority.Normal, () =>
    {
        rootFrame.Navigate(typeof(ScanPage), new ScanPageNavigationParameters
        {
            Options = options,
            ResultHandler = r =>
            {
               tcsScanResult.SetResult(r);
            },
            Scanner = this,
            ContinuousScanning = false
        });
    });

    var result = await tcsScanResult.Task;

    await dispatcher.RunAsync(CoreDispatcherPriority.High, () =>
    {
        if (rootFrame.CanGoBack)
            rootFrame.GoBack();
    });

    return result;
}
```

Everything up until this point works fine, I can navigate to the scan page and back again. As you can see, I am calling the Dispatcher to sync back to the UI thread each time. When this gets called:

```
HandleScanResult(t.Result);
```

I have the Result in t.Result so that is good. The problem is that within that method, I try to set a string on a text box on MainPage. When debugging, I can see that the Text property on the text box has the string but when the method completes, the text box is still blank. I have made sure to also wrap the setting of the text box Text property with a Dispatcher too so it is syncd to the UI thread. I get no errors or exceptions but I simply cannot set the Text or better, have the Text that it shows as set, actually show on the text box.

I suspect I have a syncronization issue maybe or maybe there are two instances of the page and it is setting one I cannot see because it is covered by another one? I don't know, i am stuck.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want use this way to pass the parameter, you need keep your original page unchanged when you call `Frame.GoBack` method. So you need set [`NavigationCacheMode`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.navigation.navigationcachemode) as `Required` for your first Page.

```
<Page <!-- some XAML code -->
      NavigationCacheMode="Required"
      >
```

What `NavigationCacheMode.Required` does is that the page is cached and the cached instance is reused for every visit regardless of the cache size for the frame. The frame is not created a new instance of the page every time when you navigate to.